# ReferenceError: utea is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So I added an economy system to my bot about 2 weeks ago and have been trying to fix the bugs with it for 4 days now and I have run into so many errors I am practically a blob glued to my chair having constant mental breakdowns trying to figure this out.

My current error I am getting is: ReferenceError: utea is not defined?

I defined utea at the beginning of my message event in my script:

```js
client.on("message", msg => { // When user sends chat message

    let userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/Storage/userData.json', 'utf8'))

    // LET VARS
    let content = msg.content.toLowerCase()
    if (msg.guild !== null) {
        // CASE COIN CURRENCY
        if (!userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id]) userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id] = {}
        if (!userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].money) userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].money = 5

        // ITEMS
        if (!userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].tea) userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].tea = 0
        if (!userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].milk) userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].milk = 0
        if (!userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].cof) userData[msg.author.id + msg.guild.id].cof = 0
        // ITEMS >B> USAGE VARS
        let utea = 0
        let umilk = 0
        let ucof = 0
    }

    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/Storage/userData.json', JSON.stringify(userData), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err)
    })
```

The line causing it:

```js
if (utea == 0) { // this line right here <<<
    // code stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is scope.

> [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) The `let` **statement** declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

In other words this variable `utea` ONLY exists inside `if (msg.guild !== null) { }` block

But if you write:

```
var utea = 0
```

See:

> [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) The `var` **statement** declares a variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

This variable will not be scoped to a block, and your code should work.

I'll say though, this is not a good practice. One of the reasons to add `let` and `const` on Ecma was to prevent misleading uses of variables in large scopes.

To continue using `let` put the variable declaration outside of the `if` statement:

```
let utea = 0

if (msg.guild !== null) {
  // ...
}

// ...

if (utea == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

utea is defined in your conditional block

> if (msg.guild !== null) { ... }

outside of the block utea is not defined